# Modeline folding not working on help file

Tags: folding, help-system, modeline

I'm writing a helpfile for a plugin, i.e. a `foo.txt`  file that goes in the plugin's `doc/` directory. At the bottom of that file I placed the following modeline:

```
vim: tw=70 ft=help fdm=marker fmr={{{,}}} fdl=0
```

Now here's the problem:

- When opened directly with `vim foo.txt`, the file is displayed with the correct foldlevel of 0 (folds delimited by markers are closed), which means the modeline was correctly interpreted.
- When opened as a help file within vim as `:help foo`, the file is displayed with folds opened, which means the modeline was *not* correctly interpreted.

So the question is: how do I get the folds to appear initialy closed when the helpfile is opened with `:help`?

Is it even possible?

Note that the problem can be tested (and hopefully reproduced) by copying
the following code to e.g. `~/.vim/doc/foo.txt`

```
*foo*
{{{
This line should appear initially folded
}}}
vim: tw=70 ft=help fdm=marker fmr={{{,}}} fdl=0
```

then comparing what happens with

```
> vim ~/.vim/doc/foo.txt
```

vs.

```
> vim
:helptags ~/.vim/doc/
:help foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim treats help files special and resets some options beofre opening them. After trying your example, what seems to work is to add an explicit `:set foldenable` to your modeline, e.g. this seems to work for me:

```
vim: tw=70 ft=help fdm=marker fmr={{{,}}} fdl=0 fen
```